# Textarea value with newlines

Tags: php, html, session

I have a html form that contains a textarea and on submission the action page validates the `$_POST` value.
If any part of the form is empty/incorrect, the page is re-directed back to the form page. To keep the user from having to input all the data again, I have loaded all the `$_POST` values into `$_SESSION` variables.

The problem is when the session data from the textarea is echo'd back into the textarea, I get `\r\n` where line breaks should be. If I use `nl2br()` it just prints out `<br />` and the same with `reg_replace`.

Is there something I should be doing to the `$_SESSION` variable or prior to make the line breaks appear properly?

```
<textarea name="job_descript" class="tarea" 
 cols="40" rows="6" placeholder="Tell us about the job">
<?php 
  if(isset($_SESSION['DESCRIPT'])){
    echo $_SESSION['DESCRIPT'];
    unset($_SESSION['DESCRIPT']);
 } ?></textarea>

function clean($str) 
{
    $str = trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
            {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}
$descript = clean($_POST['job_descript']);
$_SESSION['DESCRIPT'] = $descript;
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you put the data into the session? I'm guessing you are entering the data there in an encoded manner. (Using `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` ?)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not that advanced. Here's the code: $descript = clean($_POST['job_descript']); function clean($str) 
{
  $str = trim($str);
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
                {
   $str = stripslashes($str);
  }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
} $_SESSION['DESCRIPT'] = $descript;

Comment: Don't try to put the code in the comment... Just edit your question and put it in there, or use some pastebin/phpfiddle site.

Comment: Sorry, put the code in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are doing `mysql_real_escape_string()` before putting the data in the session, and showing it again. Thus changing `\n` into `\\n`.

`mysql_real_escape_string()` is USEFUL, don't remove it! Otherwise your database calls will be in danger.

What you can try is removing `mysql_real_escape_string()` there, and placing it somewhere just before you actually do something to the database.

Or what you can do is have 2 versions of the data... $descript and $descript_escaped. Use the first one for showing data in HTML. And use the second one in queries.

Comment: A better solution would be to use prepared statements, as `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't actually completely protect the database from SQL injection, it just makes it a lot harder

Comment: @Markasoftware actually it does completely protect. Only problem is when you run direct queries to change charsets, and leaving the mysql_* functions thinking the first charset is still being used. If you don't do that, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is safe to use.